# Adding an array to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

used php for a while but cannot get what is going on here! I've tried `array_merge()` and `array_push()` on an array to be able to add arrays to an array of existing arrays.

For example, to be able to add x and y into the same array using a loop:

```
$x = [x, y, z];
$y = [a, b, c];

$goal = [[x, y, z], [a,b,c]];
```

Feel like I am so dinged up on this problem I am missing something really obvious!
I've tried all of the following but have had nothing work.

```
$intermediate = array([x,y,z];;
$goal = array($goal, $intermediate)

$goal[$i] = $intermediate;

$goal[$i][$j] = $raw[i][j]; // lets say raw is where elements come from
```

From what I have seen this is an indexed array that is multidimensional but I am completely stuck as I have been working it for hours! Any help appreciated!

[EDIT] Essentially I am trying to push into Google sheets and it accepts input of the form `[[$val1], [$val2]]` for an insertion for two columns and of the form `[[$val1, $val2]]` for an insertion into a row.

I have a 2d array, where each array will be a separate row but it doesn't seem to be working. I am updating $goal to $goal = [$goal, $intermediates] but it doesn't seem to work - it only keeps the first line.

My goal is to push content of the form `[[$val1,$val2],[$val3,$val4]]` but it only inserts the `[$val1,$val2]` part.

```
$goal = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count( $info) ; $i++){
  $value1 = $info[$i][0]; // fname
  $value2 = $info[$i][1]; // lname
  $value3 = $info[$i][2]; // age

  $person =[$value1, $value2, $value3];


  $goal = [$goal, $person];
 
}
```

I have also tried with the array() version rather than the square brackets.

Comment: `$goal = [$x, $y];` ? Please provide an actual example of input/output, as I'm unsure what that second snippet is trying to achieve.

Comment: @Jeto sorry, I was a bit vague, I just updated my question

Comment: Do you mean l ike this? https://3v4l.org/E4kWK

Answer (score 1):

You could either, store the array into variables and create a new array from both :

```
$array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array2 = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

$outputArray = [$array1, $array2];
```

Or build it using the `[]` operator.

```
$outputArray = [];
$outputArray[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$outputArray[] = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
```

[It seams to be working fine both ways](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5deab7f8483f887304852d45ab3db1c0768628d3)

**EDIT** With your new addition, you were very close. What you need is to use the `[]` operator on the `$goal` array. This operator adds another element to an array. In our case, we want to add `$person`, since it's the newly created row.

```
$goal = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($info) ; $i++){
    
  $value1 = $info[$i][0]; // fname
  $value2 = $info[$i][1]; // lname
  $value3 = $info[$i][2]; // age

  $person =[$value1, $value2, $value3];


  $goal[] = $person;
 
}
```

You can use [this playground](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d85f5cb4a66589a45ac3ade1018c7d4722ff5196) to checkout a working example.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am looking for but it doesn't seem to be working. I updated my question to be a little more specific : )

Comment: @NewAppDeveloper I've updated my answer according to the new data you've provided. I Hope it solve your problem !

Answer (score 0):

Just use [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function:

```
<?php
$x = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
$y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$goal = [];

array_push($goal, $x, $y);

print_r($goal);
```

[Here you can play this PHP code](https://phpize.online/?phpses=6e2327ac2cf6e3ab0d4e4952cf262d5d&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)